# Get current Subscription ID

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Using the Powershell Azure module, is there a way to get the active subscription ID?

I can set the subscription using `Set-AzContext`, but `Get-AzContext` returns the subscription name without a specific `ID` column

`Get-AzSubscription` returns a list of subscriptions, but not the active subscription.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could do that with the following command:

```
(Get-AzContext).Subscription.id
```

Comment: just a hint, you can do `Get-AzContext | fl *` to discover more output, as well as `Get-AzContext | gm`