# Azure PowerShell :: how to print a list of properties

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-az-module

I found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980492/get-current-subscription-id) how to print the the Azure Subscription ID:

```
(Get-AzContext).Subscription.id
```

But if I look in the official documentation of the command [Get-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azcontext?view=azps-8.2.0) I don't see anywhere that the `.Subscription.id` or `.id` would print that information.

How the guy who replied to that question knew such information?

Where can I find a list of properties for each command?

Commmands like `Get-AzContext | fl *` or `Get-AzContext | gm` or `get-help Get-AzContext -full` don't provide such list.

I want to be able to see all properties provided by commands like `Get-AzResource` or `Get-AzSqlDatabase` or any other.

Comment: At the bottom of the documentation page for `Get-AzContext` it very clearly states it outputs objects of type `PSAzureContext` - which in turn has a [`Subscription` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.profile.models.core.psazurecontext.subscription) containing an object implementing the `IAzureSubscription` interface, which in turn declares an [`Id` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.common.authentication.abstractions.iazuresubscription.id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problably not the cleanest way, but as I use this trick very often and since I shared to some teammates I noticed they are using it now I guess it worths sharing :) .

Use the `convertto-json -depth xx` (where xx is big enough for your need and depending on the objet's complexity) to get the whole view of an object
Then you can redirect to a file and look for what you need quite easily.

In case you run `Get-AzContext | convertto-json -depth 10` you will find back the subscription and the ID.

Comment: `Format-Custom * -Force` might be helpful here too.